# How to handle properties of a dbus interface with python?

Tags: python, linux, dbus

I'm about to work on an implementation of [mpris](http://mpris.org). But currently I am not sure how to read/write dbus interface properties with python-dbus. Is there any examples for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got the answer:

```
@dbus.service.method(dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE, in_signature='ss', out_signature='v')
def Get(self, interface, prop):
    ...
@dbus.service.method(dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE, in_signature='ssv')
def Set(self, interface, prop, value):
    ...
@dbus.service.method(dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE, in_signature='s', out_signature='a{sv}')
def GetAll(self, interface):
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, could you tell me how you found (link maybe)?