# MPRIS + Python (dbus): reading and writing properties

Tags: python, linux, dbus

I have already checked this link: [How to handle properties of a dbus interface with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277814/how-to-handle-properties-of-a-dbus-interface-with-python). However, that only lists an API... but I don't know where that API comes from.

I just started working with dbus (pretty excited about this, to be honest ^__^ just not too happy with the documentation I've found) on python and I was wondering if I could just get some sample code.

I'm using MPRIS specifically for Rhythmbox, although it 'should' be the same for all.

I know I can access and have fun witht he methods by doing the following:

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
proxy = bus.get_object('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.rhythmbox','/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2')
player = dbus.Interface(proxy, 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player')
playlists = dbus.Interface(proxy, 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Playlists')
tracklist = dbus.Interface(proxy, 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.TrackList')
```

However, I wish to know about properties. Some sample code will suffice :) Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Found how.

```
proxy = bus.get_object('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.rhythmbox','/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2')
properties_manager = dbus.Interface(proxy, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
properties_manager.Set('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player', 'Volume', 100.0)
curr_volume = properties_manager.Get('org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player', 'Volume')
```

Pretty simple indeed :) I thought it would be simple like this.

Comment: Were you able to write metadata, such as setting a song's rating?

Comment: Effective, but what a pain! You'd think there'd be an easier way.

Comment: By the way, if you found out how to do this via some online resource (as opposed to looking through source code), could you post the link?

Comment: Won't lie, I don't remember how I found out. I can't even find the source code for this project (I wanted to continue it just 2 months ago). It is -very- likely that I checked through the source code, though.